# Import 3rd party library

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I need to import an 3rd party library in an angular2 project.

Here is what I did:

```
ng new myproject
npm install --save createjs-easeljs
npm install @types/easeljs
```

Now is the moment I am stuck. How do I import and use this library? There are objects like `Shape` or `Stage`

```
import { Shape, Stage } from '../../../node_modules/createjs-easeljs/lib/easeljs-0.8.2.min.js';
```

This does not work at all.

My folder structure:

```
dynam194:src timo$ tree -L 2
.
├── app
│   ├── app.component.css
│   ├── app.component.html
│   ├── app.component.spec.ts
│   ├── app.component.ts
│   ├── app.module.ts
│   └── canvas
├── assets
├── environments
│   ├── environment.prod.ts
│   └── environment.ts
├── favicon.ico
├── index.html
├── main.ts
├── polyfills.ts
├── styles.css
├── test.ts
├── tsconfig.json
└── typings
    └── easeljs.d.ts
```

tsconfig.json

```
"paths": {
  "easeljs": ["../node_modules/createjs-easeljs/lib/easeljs-0.8.2.min.js"]
},
"sourceMap": true,
"target": "es5",
"typeRoots": [
  "../node_modules/@types",
  "typings",
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a path (and a `baseUrl`) to your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "baseUrl: ".",
    "paths": {
      "easeljs": ["../node_modules/createjs-easeljs/lib/easeljs-0.8.2.min.js"]
    },
  }
}
```

with the path to `easeljs` being relative to your `tsconfig.json`.

After that you can import this library using:

```
import * as createjs from 'easeljs';
```

And use it inside your project like:

```
let stage: createjs.Stage = new createjs.Stage('myCanvas');
let shape: createjs.Shape = new createjs.Shape();
```

Because the `@types` definition files all have their own way of defining modules, its likely you come across one that's not compatible with that way of importing. As far as i know though, they want to make that the standard.

You should create a local typings folder and create a `easeljs.d.ts` file containing:

```
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/@types/easeljs/index.d.ts" />

declare module "createjs" {
    export = createjs;
}
```

Make sure the reference path is pointing to the right directory, I don't know your project structure :)

After that add the local typings folder to the `typeRoots` property of your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types",
      "typings/local"
    ]
   }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Apparently, this does not work for this library. Unfortunately. Good thing angular-cli has an option to preload scripts:

edit your `angular-cli.json` to add the library:

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      ...
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/createjs-easeljs/lib/easeljs-0.8.2.min.js"
      ],
    }
  ]
}
```

Do not use an import on top of your file, so remove `import * as createjs from 'easeljs'`. And no need for the local typings folder. Also remove the `paths` in your `tsconfig.json`

Comment: I am getting the following error: `Module build failed: Error: /myproject/src/app/canvas/canvas.component.ts (2,27): File '/myproject/node_modules/@types/easeljs/index.d.ts' is not a module.)` where 2,27 is the import you just wrote.

Comment: That's an annoying trait of `@types`. I've updated my answer

Comment: Hm, doesn't seem to work. Same error. My typings path is `./typings` thats what I did differently. I did also changed the ref path to `...@types/easeljs/index.d.ts...`. Maybe its a naming issue of createjs/easeljs?

Comment: I've just installed `easeljs` in my own project, and it works just as I described. You were right though that the ref path was wrong. I've updated my answer accordingly. Are you sure you put in the right path inside your `tsconfig.json`? It looks like it is pointing towards a `.d.ts` file in your case, but it should point to the `.min.js`

Comment: and your `tsconfig.json` is inside a `src` folder?

Comment: I included additional information in my inital post

Comment: You must be doing something 'wrong'. It works just as I explained. Maybe update to the latest `angular-cli`? It makes no sense that the error is `'myproject/node_modules/@types/easeljs/index.d.ts' is not a module`.

Comment: Can you publish your project structure somewhere? I will figure it out what I am doing wrong

Comment: I think I know what's wrong. You have to update your TypeScript version to `2.1.5`. I'm guessing you are still at `2.0.x` :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134395/discussion-between-sad-tuna-and-pierreduc).

Comment: One final question: Do I have to install @types/easeljs?

Comment: Not necessarily, only if you want type hinting. Otherwise you have to put a `declare const createjs: any` somewhere.. which is ugly :) so yes, do keep the typings! Is everything working now?

Comment: Like a charm. Thank you very much!